# Powermail redirect not working with double opt

Tags: typo3-7.6.x, powermail

i have developed custom redirect based on selected value in a field on "double opt in" enable form but redirection not working

after debuging i found reason

added and commented on this Plain Text snippet: Untitled

```
public function redirectToUriFinisher()
    {
        /** @var RedirectUriService $redirectService */
        $redirectService = $this->objectManager->get(RedirectUriService::class, $this->contentObject);
        $uri = $redirectService->getRedirectUri();
        if (!empty($uri) && $this->isRedirectEnabled()) {
            HttpUtility::redirect($uri);
        }
    }
    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function isRedirectEnabled()
    {
        return !(!empty($this->settings['main']['optin']) && empty($this->arguments['hash']));
    }
```

in Classes/Finisher/RedirectFinisher.php line 62 there is condition

but not getting how to set hash in argument

Comment: I was lazy when I saw this and just added a rewrite to that finisher, so it always returns true. My TS Condition takes care of the rewrite, ie. when it triggers so its no "stupid" solution imho.